# How can I add all this into a NSLog

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have everything working but how would I make it all in one line. Is there a place holder?

NSLog(@"The value of myFraction is: "  [myFraction print], [myFraction divide] );

```
    // [myFraction print];
    // [myFraction divide];
```

Print i have it set that it shows numerator and denominator (5/20) and divide that it divides numberator / denominator and has NSLog of the total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anybody stumbles upon my question I have finally figured it out. In the implementation section you have to make a method and return it.

```
-(void) setNumerator: (int)n {
   numberator = n;
}
 -(int) numerator {
   return numerator; 
}
```

then after when you want to NSLog it you do

```
[myFraction setNumerator: 10];
NSLog(@"My fraction is %i", [myFraction numerator]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the appropriate [**String Format Specifier**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1) (visit that page to find the correct one for your needs). For example, printing out those two values as floats:

```
NSLog(@"The value of myFraction is %f printed, and %f divided.", [myFraction print], [myFraction divide]);
```

Will print (for example):

**The value of myFraction is 3.45 printed, and 1.847 divided.**

Some quick references for you are **%@** for strings, **%d** for doubles, and **%i** for integers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a fraction class with simple interface.

```
@implementation MyFraction

- (instancetype)initWithNumerator:(NSInteger)numerator denominator:(NSInteger)denominator
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.numerator = numerator;
        self.denominator = denominator;
    }
    return self;
}
- (NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The value of myFraction is: %ld / %ld = %f", (long)self.numerator, (long)self.denominator, [self answer]];
}
- (double)answer;
{
    if(self.denominator == 0) {
        NSLog(@"denominator must not be 0 value.");
        return NAN;
    }
    else {
        return self.numerator / (double)self.denominator;
    }
}

@end
```

Usage:

```
MyFraction *f = [[MyFraction alloc] initWithNumerator:5 denominator:20];
NSLog(@"%@", f);
```

Result :

```
The value of myFraction is: 5 / 20 = 0.250000
```

Comment: Im getting "argument type void is incomplete"

Answer (score -1):

```
NSLog(@"The value of myFraction is %f printed, and %f divided.", [myFraction print], [myFraction divide]);
```